# Cannot open database "DummyCRMOrg_MSCRM" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011

I am logged in to a dev VM as the domain admin and I have SysAdmin rights in SQl Server yest I get this error when installing Dynamics CRM 2013

Cannot open database "DummyCRMOrg_MSCRM" requested by the login. The login failed.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your first time installing CRM 2013?

Check out this article.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/91868/173478.aspx

There is a whole setup for delegation and trusting to be performed.  The place of the web server, application server and database server a key to a good install.

For reference: 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh699751.aspx
http://blog.sonomapartners.com/2007/04/kerberos_and_de.html